# How to find nearest address by lat,long

Tags: mysql, distance, latitude-longitude

I have created a location table where lat,long and location are saved. My requirement is when I pass a lat,long , will get the nearest location within 10 miles from that location table. Location table structure is as follows:-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `locations` (
  `latitude` float(14,12) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `longitude` float(14,12) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `location` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`latitude`,`longitude`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and 
My query is :-

```
  SELECT 
    (3959 * ACOS(COS(RADIANS(lat)) * COS(RADIANS(latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(longitude) - RADIANS(long)) + SIN(RADIANS(lat)) * SIN(RADIANS(latitude)))) AS distance,
    location
FROM
    locations
HAVING distance < 10
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 0 , 1
```

I am using MySql 5.6. 
There are around 39 thousands data in location table.
When this query executes it is taking 5 to 6 second.

Can anybody help out how could I reduce the execution time?

Thanks!

Comment: While it seems like a lot more code, I suspect that 'WHERE (3959 etc...' will be significantly faster. And is there really no chance that an address might be in Anchorage, Alaska, say?

Comment: It is a tough problem.  But the code [here](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng) will do it much faster.  But it requires significant changes to your schema.

Comment: Do not use `(M,N)` on `FLOAT`.  Also (14,12) will chop longitudes at 100; probably not what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL supports [geospatial datatypes and functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-extensions.html) - these are optimized and much faster than doing this through integers and geometry function. There are a number of tutorials on the web - [this one](http://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-5-7-and-gis-an-example/) is pretty good.

Comment: Should MySQL 5.6 support geospatial data types?